# combining multiple regex into single

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I have long string and I want to replace some chars with empty.
I have following regex

1. 1st I want to remove all url from string, for which I have regex
   `/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/i`
2. Next I want to remove all word which starts with Car followed by nine digits. Car word should case insensitive, regex for that `/car\s*\d{9}/i`
3. And Last I want to remove all special chars from string, regex for that `/[^\w\s]/gi`

So my input string like below

**Input**
`Hell Test https://regex101.com with special Car123456789dgd cha cAr12345678racters @##!$#!@Hekki`

**Output**`Hell Test with special dgd cha cAr12345678racters Hekki`

currently I have to do 3 separate operation to do this, Is there any way I can combine these regex into one?

I try to join using `|` but didn't work.
`(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/i)|(/car\s*\d{9}/i)|(/[^\w\s]/gi)`

Comment: use `|` to combine

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it tried that `(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/i)|(/car\s*\d{9}/i)|(/[^\w\s]/gi)`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/eittmt/1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `|` to combine:

```js
const str = 'Hell Test https://regex101.com with special Car123456789dgd cha cAr12345678racters @##!$#!@Hekki';
console.log(str.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|car\s*\d{9}|[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
```